# Code output missing in Rmarkdown document pushed to Github

Tags: github, rstudio, r-markdown

I want to publish an R Markdown file in RStudio to Github.  I am able to commit the R Markdown file and push it to Github.  Although it appears there, the code output is not included.

https://github.com/matsuobasho/nb/blob/master/markdowntest4.Rmd

When I view the document in RStudio, the code output is in fact there.

What am I missing?

Comment: what do you mean by code output? Do you mean the result of `summary(cars)` ? you would have to knit the Rmd file first

Comment: By code output I mean the output of the summary function that I run.  If I knit the rmd file, how do I then get it into github from RStudio?  When I click knit, I get the output in an html browser.

Comment: commit and push the html file. But the idea of rmarkdown is that it is reproducible ; if you can share your data or they are public, then anyone with the Rmd file will be able to reproduce your analysis

Comment: I don't see a way to save the rmd file as html in RStudio and then be able to push it to Github.  The outptu of knit is an md file.

Comment: use knit to html or add `output: html_document` in your yaml front matter